# Reference on the time it takes for a source code used for a research article to be released

Tags: computer-science, code, reference-request, open-science

Is there any research/study/survey/... that looked at how much time it takes for the authors of a research article to release the source code? Ideally I'm looking for an approximation distribution.

This question is a follow-up of [Reference on availability of source code used in computer science research articles?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/29137/452)

Comment: Are you asking about how much time the authors typically invest in preparing the code, or about how much time passes between when the article is ready and when the research code is ready?  Either way, there is a lot of potential ambiguity here.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson   I'm asking how much time passes between when the article is ready and when the research code is ready. What else should I clarify?

Comment: What do you mean by "ready"?  When a preprint is posted to arXiv?  When the manuscript is submitted?  Accepted?  Electronically published?  Print published?  And what do you mean by releasing the code -- especially in the case that it is developed in a publicly accessible repository?

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Ready = made available online. I'm fine with other definitions too (since there haven't been that many answers so far…). Releasing the code = make the code that was used for the paper publicly available.