# Study of code share practices in science

Tags: reference-request, code

I am searching for a study that presents statistics of how often you can get code that claims to be available in scientific communities. I found the following interesting study, which is very similar to what I am looking for: http://reproducibility.cs.arizona.edu/

However, this one is specific to computer science, and I wonder if something similar has been done in biology, physics or other research areas. I appreciate your hints and clues.

Comment: If you find more studies on code availability in computer science please let me know here: [Reference on availability of source code used in computer science research articles?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/29137/452)

Comment: I doubt that most departments are even aware of what source code their researchers are using; some departments see source code as something like how you organize your desk: specific to you and disinteresting to everyone else.  Your survey may require a lot of tracking down people and doing personal interviews to get reliable data.

Answer (score 2):

This study is more qualitative than quantitative but might provide you with some more information about the scientific software space.

James Howison, Ewa Deelman, Michael J. McLennan, Rafael Ferreira da Silva, James D. Herbsleb; [Understanding the scientific software ecosystem and its impact: Current and future measures](https://academic.oup.com/rev/article/24/4/454/1518466/Understanding-the-scientific-software-ecosystem). Res Eval 2015; 24 (4): 454-470. doi: 10.1093/reseval/rvv014