# How much do for-profit companies pay for journal subscriptions?

Tags: publications, publishers

We have these figures for universities: [Reference for annual journal subscription costs paid per university?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29923/reference-for-annual-journal-subscription-costs-paid-per-university?newreg=83080785ca804db2ba10f88f5bace54f)

Do we have similar figures for companies (in theory, the ultimate end user)? For example, is Pfizer subscribed to any journals, and if so, how much are they paying?

Comment: This question is similar to asking how high are the fees a private company is paying when receiving a payment via credit cards. The answer is: it depends, and it is a commercial "secret". Please report back your findings!